# Tensorflow multiple optimizers on multi-output model. Get trainable variables for one of the outputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, optimization, neural-network, multipleoutputs

My goal is to use `tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer` to use a different optimizer for each output of my model. In order to do that I need the layers that feed in to this output, but am unsure how to get those. We can get the `model.trainable_variables` but this is all the trainable variables and not just those that feed into a given output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way, but by workaround was to create separate models.
Note that using ModelCheckpoint with model.fit will return "not json serializable" error in model.fit. We need to set `save_weights_only = True`

```
model = KM.Model(inputs = [in1, in2],outputs=[out1, out2])
model_out1 = KM.Model(inputs = [in1, in2],outputs=[out1])
model_out2 = KM.Model(inputs = [in1, in2],outputs=[out2])
out1_layers = [model.get_layer(j.name) for j in model_out1.layers]
out2_layers = [model.get_layer(j.name) for j in model_out2.layers]
```